# Yii criteria - порядок джойнов

Tags: php, yii

Нужно вручную в критерии сделать left join.
Делаю так:

```
$criteria->join = "LEFT OUTER JOIN ".
                OfferBlockAbuse::model()->tableName()." `BlockedOffers`
                ON
                (
                   BlockedOffers.publisher_id = :pub_account_id 
                   AND BlockedOffers.type_publisher_id = 'Account'
                   OR BlockedOffers.publisher_id = :pub_profile_id 
                   AND BlockedOffers.type_publisher_id = 'Profile'
                )
                AND
                (
                   (BlockedOffers.item_id = t.id 
                        AND BlockedOffers.type_item_id = 'Offer')
                   OR (BlockedOffers.item_id = Account.id 
                        AND BlockedOffers.type_item_id = 'Account')
                   OR (BlockedOffers.item_id = company.id 
                        AND BlockedOffers.type_item_id = 'Profile')
                )
                AND BlockedOffers.is_blocked = 'Yes'
                AND BlockedOffers.show_for_pub = 'No'";
```

Дело в том, что в критерии джойнятся еще `relations`. Например `Account`. А этот джойн в запросе первый и `Account.id` он еще не видит.

Как поставить этот джойн в конец запроса? Или как написать такую сложную связь модели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sup>Вынесенный ответ из тела вопроса</sup>*

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
relations()
{
...
'BlockedOffers'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'OfferBlockAbuse', '', 'together'=>true),
}

$criteria->with = array(
...
'BlockedOffers'  => array(
                'select' => 'id',
                'on'=>"
                    (
                       BlockedOffers.publisher_id = :pub_account_id
                       AND BlockedOffers.type_publisher_id = 'Account'
                       OR BlockedOffers.publisher_id = :pub_profile_id
                       AND BlockedOffers.type_publisher_id = 'Profile'
                    )
                    AND
                    (
                       (BlockedOffers.item_id = t.id
                            AND BlockedOffers.type_item_id = 'Offer')
                       OR (BlockedOffers.item_id = Account.id
                            AND BlockedOffers.type_item_id = 'Account')
                       OR (BlockedOffers.item_id = company.id
                            AND BlockedOffers.type_item_id = 'Profile')
                    )
                    AND BlockedOffers.is_blocked = 'Yes'
                    AND BlockedOffers.show_for_pub = 'No'
                    "
            ),
)
```

Не знал, что можно пустую связь оставлять.